# Is there a way to warn wrong clock domain crossing in Chisel3?

Tags: hdl, chisel

As I read from [Chisel wiki](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Multiple-Clock-Domains), it is possible to declare several clock domain in a single module.

But if we need to read/write a signal through two different clock domains it's important to manage metastability (with dual d-latch, asynchronous fifo, ...).

If we don't manage it, it's a design error. Is there a way to ask chisel checking wrong clock domain crossing in design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. This is a needed, but as of yet unimplemented feature.

Comment: Ok, I added the request on github : https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/1085